# How do I make a list item element sticky?

Tags: html, css

How can I make the list item with class `c` sticky in this structure? When I say sticky I mean `.c { position: sticky; }` in relation to the other list items?

What I'm trying to do is that the end user scrolls down and the sticky list item is always visible.

```html
<div class="a">
  <ul class="b">
    <li class="c"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise to explain what "sticky" means here. Provide more code so we have some context.

Comment: You mean `.c { position: sticky; }`? Please [edit] your question to show what research you've done and what attempts you've made based on that research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To always keep the first item visible you can use `position: sticky`.

```css
ul {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    background: white;
}

li:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #f1f1f1;
}

li:first-child {
    position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>First list item</li>
    <li>Second list item</li>
    <li>Third list item</li>
    <li>Fourth list item</li>
    <li>Fifth list item</li>
    <li>Sixth list item</li>
</ul>
```